# Add temporary column for insert stored procedure in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-insert, alter-table

I am trying to add a temporary column to a target table and use that column in a where clause to insert new data into a parent table via stored procedure that I am using for a one-to-one relationship from parent to target table (see code below).  I am getting an error with the alter table add column statement thus resulting in the IMPORT_NUMBER being an invalid identifier.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'ALTER TABLE TARGET_TABLE ADD IMPORT_NUMBER NUMBER';

INSERT
INTO
TARGET_TABLE(
existing_col_1,
existing_col_2,
existing_col_3,
IMPORT_NUMBER
)
SELECT
STAGED_TABLE.value1,
STAGED_TABLE.value2,
STAGED_TABLE.value3,
STAGED_TABLE.IMPORT_NUMBER
FROM
STAGED_TABLE
GROUP BY
IMPORT_NUMBER;

UPDATE
PARENT_TABLE
SET
target_table_id =(
SELECT
TARGET_TABLE.id
FROM
TARGET_TABLE
WHERE
TARGET_TABLE.IMPORT_NUMBER = PARENT_TABLE.IMPORT_NUMBER
)
WHERE
PARENT_TABLE.IMPORT_NUMBER IS NOT NULL;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE TARGET_TABLE DROP COLUMN IMPORT NUMBER';
```

Comment: Are you sure it is your add column that is failing and not the drop column?  The drop column as the "NUMBER" datatype listed, which shouldn't be there.   The SELECT portion of the INSERT I would expect to fail as well, since you are selecting 4 values but only grouping by 1.

Comment: ...or, rather, NUMBER in that position is not the data type. The underscore is missing; it should be DROP COLUMN IMPORT_NUMBER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a stored procedure, the entire procedure is parsed and validated at the time of `create or replace procedure`. At the time the procedure is created the column `IMPORT_NUMBER` does not exist, so the insert and update statements can not be validated.

I would try to find a solution that does not include DDL if possible. Can the column be made a permanent part of the table?

If you must follow this path, the insert and update statements will need to be in strings and passed to `execute immediate` or `DBMS_SQL` so that they are parsed and validated at run time, after the column is created.

Comment: This makes sense.  Thank you!